# Foam board sheets

Tags: insulation

I have a new tiny home shell in east texas. What's the best way to insulate it?

#1. Can I use 1/2" foamular on exterior or do I need to use a foiled foam sheet?

#2. Can I put more foamular between the studs on the inside for better protection along with fiberglass insulation, or would I need a thicker foam sheet on the inside? I would peel the thickness of the foamular off the fiberglass faced insulation so both fit between the studs.

Comment: Why are you duplicating your question?

Comment: Best, you ask? Professional spray foam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add foam board insulation to my tiny house to increase energy efficiency?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/217161/can-i-add-foam-board-insulation-to-my-tiny-house-to-increase-energy-efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

A question of budget and existing wall stud thickness. Spray foam is a good insulator and adds stiffness to the build but $. If on a budget I prefer 2' EPS or Graphite Polystyrene boards cut to size between the studs then filled the gaps between boards and studs with expanding foam. About an R7 with no air infiltration and leaves room for wiring in front of insulation. No fiber necessary unless you're going into very cold climates. If so you can add rock wool panels if you have the room. One step further with 1/4 fomular fanfold to the outside for a thermal break.